# Split string column into multiple new columns in R

Tags: r, regex, string, list

I have a column of data that looks like this :

```
data.frame(Weather=c("Breezy Temp: 68° F, Humidity: 66%, Wind: W 15 mph","N/A Temp: ° F, Wind:   mph")
```

I would like to pull out all the numbers (extract the numbers from the string) but I would like to keep them in separate columns.

The result would ideally look like:

`Row 1: 68 66 15`
`Row 2: NA NA NA (Blanks will do, too)`

So far, I've been able to do this:

```
(str_extract_all(Data$Column,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?"))
```

But I just get a list that looks like this;

[[1]]
[1] "68" ","  ","  ","  "66" ","  ","  ","  "15"

[[2]]
[1] ","

Instead of being able to break this up into 3 columns for every row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R`.  We replace one or more nondigit (`\\D+`) with a `,` in `gsub` on the 'Weather' column, then read with `read.csv` to create multiple column and `Filter` out the columns that have all `NA` elements

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), 
  read.csv(text = gsub("\\D+", ",", df1$Weather), 
         fill = TRUE, header = FALSE))
```

-output

```
#  V2 V3 V4
#1 68 66 15
#2 NA NA NA
```

---

Using the new data

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), 
   read.csv(text = gsub("\\D+", ",", df2$Weather), 
          fill = TRUE, header = FALSE))
#  V2 V3 V4 V5
#1 68 66 15 NA
#2 NA NA NA NA
#3 76 68  6 10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Weather = c("Breezy Temp: 68° F, Humidity: 66%, Wind: W 15 mph", 
"N/A Temp: ° F, Wind:   mph")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(Weather = c("Breezy Temp: 68° F, Humidity: 66%, Wind: W 15 mph", 
"N/A Temp: ° F, Wind:   mph", "Cloudy Temp: 76° F, Humidity: 68%, Wind: SW 6 mph, Gusts to 10 mph"
 )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately my solution data frame is only two columns wide rather than 3 when I apply it myself. (and the length of the data frame is longer than the length of the original column)

Comment: @ArianModarres Please check the patterns in your data.  I removed everything not a digit with `gsub` and inserted a `,` for that.  THen, I read with `read.csv`.  If you can show more data, then I can test

Comment: I am looking to see if there are any anomalies in that data column but it seems like every row has the same and standard formatting as the ones I provided in the example. The dataset is massive however so I may not be able to see if one row is a different format. Could you think of what may be causing the difference in our outputs? Perhaps add a third row: "N/A (Indoors) Temp: ° F, Wind:   mph"

Comment: @ArianModarres Based on the data you showed, it is working perfectly fine for me

Comment: I found the problem. Please add this line into the data: "Cloudy Temp: 76° F, Humidity: 68%, Wind: SW 6 mph, Gusts to 10 mph". I guess one can add a 4th column for every row, and this should alleviate the issue.

Comment: df1 <- structure(list(Weather = c("Breezy Temp: 68° F, Humidity: 66%, Wind: W 15 mph", 
"N/A Temp: ° F, Wind:   mph","Cloudy Temp: 76° F, Humidity: 68%, Wind: SW 6 mph, Gusts to 10 mph")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))   This should do it

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't seem to generalize to my entire data column, no matter what I've tried. I could potentially upload a datafile with the entire column- but I'm not sure I can. I continuously get an answer with 2 columns, where your answer would extend the column length according to the maximum number of numbers in the data rows

Comment: @ArianModarres I tried both your examples and it is working for me.

Comment: @ArianModarres if you can post your data in github and sent the link I can take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, it works for both examples when I try it as well. The issue is not the code; in all likelihood the issue is that the data column has an anomaly row which causes the problem, so this code doesn't generalize to the entire data frame.

Comment: @ArianModarres okay fair.  Without knowing that issue, it is difficult to know how to change the code

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was a rather elegant solution !